# why is self.navigationController.visibleViewController returning true on view controller that is not visible

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Currently, I have a navigation stack set up in the following manner:

`ViewController A` -> `ViewController B` -> `ViewController C` -> `ViewController D`

In the implementation code for both `ViewController` C and `ViewController D`, I have a selector that will only run through a code block if the following test is met

```
if (self.navigationController.visibleViewController)
```

The problem I am facing is that the above test is always returning true for `ViewController C`. First, I launch my application in the IOS simulator and I navigate up the stack all the way to View Controller D. Once `ViewController D` loads up, I press the "home" button on my simulator. After pressing the home button, I click on my app once again and relaunch my application (enters foreground). What occurs now is strange, the view controller that is visible to me is `ViewController D`, because that is the View Controller I was last at. Although `ViewController D` is now currently the only view controller that is visible to me, the above if statement is returning true for `ViewController C` as well! (I only want `ViewController D's` selector code to be executed, this is a problem).

So this begs the question, what exactly does it mean to be a `visibleViewController` and how can I make it so that `ViewController C's` selector does not execute if `ViewController D` is the view controller that appears before me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `visibleViewController` is a property that returns the controller that is currently visible, not a boolean property returning `YES` or `NO` depending on whether or not the current controller is visible. As long as there is a visible view controller on the screen - any controller at all - the check of `self.navigationController.visibleViewController` will return `YES`, because any non-`nil` value passed to an `if` is considered a `YES`.

The check should be as follows:

```
if (self == self.navigationController.visibleViewController)
```

The comparison will return `YES` if the current view controller is the visible view controller of the navigation controller, and `NO` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

visibleViewController will always return an object (at least with your setup) which makes your if statement always true -- it doesn't return true only if the controller you have that code in is on screen. Instead you should use self.view.window as the test. It will only return true if self's view is on screen.

You could also still use self.navigationController.visibleViewController, but compare it to self to see if they're the same.